# I hear clicking in audio with a DirectShow graph created with Graph Edit yet player software on my PC plays audio smoothly

Tags: audio, directshow, playback, directsound, graphedit

I have a DirectShow application that I built with Delphi 6 using the DSPACK component library.  For two days I have been trying to *solve* a problem with audio playback.  When I run the filter graph I create I hear repetitive clicks in the playback.  What was really confusing was that the audio file I created simultaneously with my filter graph had clean continuous audio, not gaps.  So I knew that the audio buffers were being delivered properly but something I was doing was "jamming up" the "live" playback.  Or so I thought.  I spent two days diagnosing the problem looking for semaphores being held too long (locks) or perhaps timestamp problems, which I documented in this other Stack Overflow post:

[Getting stuttering during rendering of my DirectShow filter despite output file being "smooth"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331012/getting-stuttering-during-rendering-of-my-directshow-filter-despite-output-file)

A few minutes ago I decided to try a test with the Graph Edit utility.  I created a dead simple graph consisting of just the capture device I was using (VOIP phone microphone), and the renderer device I was using (*HD ATI Rear Audio* output to headphones).  Two filters total.  **Much to my surprise I heard the same clicking.**  So here was a case that did not involve my code at all and I heard clicking.

Then I changed the audio renderer in the Graph Edit created filter graph to the *VOIP phone ear piece*.  The clicking went away.

Now I know there's a way to get smooth audio on ut the ATI Rear Audio device since its the preferred audio output device and everything from videos I play on my PC to wave files I play on it sound flawless.  So are the other software programs doing something different than just connecting filters?  I am wondering if perhaps the default mode for the *HD ATI Rear Audio* is without double-buffering and perhaps those other software programs know how to enable that feature?  Or are they doing something else, perhaps using another DirectShow or DirectSound filter or technique for example, to make the audio play smoothly on the *HD ATI Rear Audio* renderer?

Answer (score 0):

What you possibly having (depends on actual stuttering though) is that when you are using capture and playback devices backed by different hardware, their sampling rates slightly differ. For example, you capture 22050 Hz at actual rate of (22050 - 2%) Hz and you play it back with hardware consuming bytes at (22050 + 2%) Hz.

Now obviously this won't work out smooth: eventually playback will experience data underlow... If you save into file and play back from file, it will go smooth as the file will be able to supply data at the rate of playback device. If capture and playback devices are the same hardware, they are likely to use shared "hardware" clock and rates match.

The problem is known as "rate matcing" and is discussed on MSDN in [Live Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section.